# Build Ubuntu from local source mirrors

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, source-code, debootstrap

Currently, we are using Android on our embedded system.

When we fetch the Android source code, we get the actual git repository of every packages inside the system. We can then mirror locally and generate the whole system from our local mirror.

We'd like to try and do the same with Ubuntu.

After a bit of investigation, it looks like we need to get bazaar repository of the base packages required by debootstrap. Mirror those locally and have our build server generate deb packages from them. Then have debootstrap fetch from those locally built packages when we need to create the filesystem.

We are in early investigation so I'm sure a lot of glue is missing in this plan but does this look viable target?

Any hints that could help us out?

Comment: How often do you intend to rebuild the entire system from source?

Comment: It will be rebuilt every night if something was modified during the day. Normally on our main development tree, this means pretty much every day.